# How to using Xcode 11 to running app on iPhone 11 with iOS 15?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode11

I want to using Xcode11 to test apps on my iPhone 11 with iOS 15 installed, but currently seems the Xcode11 cannot identify the device. I don't want to install the latest Xcode 13 nor upgrade my macOS, is there any way to resolve this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Maybe with de DeviceSupport: https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport or https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport  ?

Comment: Hi Larme, I've tried this before but it doesn't work... Xcode 11 still unable identify my iPhone 11 which shows up a unknow device icon.

Answer (score 0):

There may be hacks available, but generally speaking these will cause issues. The only approved way is to install the latest Xcode. If you need to keep Xcode 12 (due to bugs or other issues inside 13), you can have both installed on your machine at the same time without any extra software or hacky setups. MacOS only cares about unique application names. You can download both one by one and simply rename one or both of them in the applications folder.

[image]

Also Xcode 13 doesn't require the latest MacOS to run, they always support the latest and the previous MacOS. So you should be able to download that no problem (unless your MacOS is many years old which is a bad idea anyway).

Comment: You sure about that? Last time I update the Xcode to 11 it require me to upgrade the macOS in order to using the Xcode... Which is kind of mandatory. That's my concerns here.

Comment: If you are running Big Sur then you can use Xcode 13; Monterey hasn't been released yet.

Comment: @J.Zeng it does tell you the compatibility on the app store. Got o xcode and scroll down to "Information" and it mentions it under compatibility. I don't recall any Xcode ever being released that required the very latest MacOS. Apples support matrix is always at least the upcoming OS and the last one released, sometimes going further back

Comment: Well, I just double-checked that it does require me to install the Big Sur to using Xcode 13. But I am still using Catalina which like said I don't want to using Bit Sur.

Comment: @J.Zeng you never mentioned you were on catalina you just said "I don't want to update". You've not read the comments from me or paul then, as Paul also said Big Sur is required, but Monterrey is not. Monterrey is the newest one, due out very soon, Big Sur is the current MacOS which has been out for over a year. Regardless of this current Xcode 13 issue, you should absolutely not still bel on catalina. Dozens and Dozens of security updates have gone into BigSur. You don't always need to be on the bleeding edge downloading new OS's immediately, but you need to stay more up to date than this

Comment: Annoyingly on a refurbished mac mini late 2012 model you cannot update to Big Sur without manually installing from a flash drive it seems. So i cant run on my IOS 15 device from xcode without either manual installing big sur on this machine or buying a totally new mac?